# ADFS SSO Implementation

Tags: adfs3.0

**Use Case scenario:**

We have lot of applications and users can access the applications based on its role application and its individual user permissions.
User should be able to use Single Sign-on

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of claims rules in ADFS.

One is the standard "get attribute from AD".

The other kind is an access rule e.g. "if member of group x, allow access". This is on a RP basis.

For these kinds of rules to work the roles (security groups) have to be in AD.

Also there are default claims rules for groups that require these to be in AD.